# How to convert a list of series to list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of series:

```
[0    1.738976
 1    1.230319
 2    1.238717
 3    1.224020
 4    1.071875
 dtype: float64, 5    1.132621
 6    1.116945
 7    0.922949
 8    1.101268
 9    1.065996
 dtype: float64, 10    1.020927
 11    1.022459
 12    1.034100
 13    0.995297
 14    1.036040
 dtype: float64, 15    1.245819
 16    1.364338
 17    0.989574
 18    1.024846
 19    0.979776
 dtype: float64, 20    1.583318
 21    1.561273
 22    1.795929
 23    1.769475
 24    1.757718
 dtype: float64, 25    1.040522
 26    1.022886
 27    0.724544
 28    0.718666
 29    0.736302
 dtype: float64, 30    0.721605
 31    0.842607
 32    0.827911
 33    0.818113
 34    2.153058
 dtype: float64, 35    2.303698
 36    2.402411
 37    2.233889
 38    3.288128
 39    2.579750
 dtype: float64]
```

I want to put all the values of series in one list. I tried:

```
a = [list_of_series]
a1 = reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, a)
```

But the output is Nan values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
s = pd.concat(L)
```

---

```
L = [s1,s2,s3]
print (L)
[0    1.738976
1    1.230319
2    1.238717
3    1.224020
4    1.071875
Name: val, dtype: float64, 5    1.132621
6    1.116945
7    0.922949
8    1.101268
9    1.065996
Name: val, dtype: float64, 10    1.020927
11    1.022459
12    1.034100
13    0.995297
14    1.036040
Name: val, dtype: float64]
```

```
s = pd.concat(L)
print (s)
0     1.738976
1     1.230319
2     1.238717
3     1.224020
4     1.071875
5     1.132621
6     1.116945
7     0.922949
8     1.101268
9     1.065996
10    1.020927
11    1.022459
12    1.034100
13    0.995297
14    1.036040
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

```
print ([s])
[0     1.738976
1     1.230319
2     1.238717
3     1.224020
4     1.071875
5     1.132621
6     1.116945
7     0.922949
8     1.101268
9     1.065996
10    1.020927
11    1.022459
12    1.034100
13    0.995297
14    1.036040
Name: val, dtype: float64]
```